# CSS3 Navigation with Transitions and flyout

Tags: css, navigation, css-transitions, modernizr

I am working on a `css3` menu and I can't get it to work exactly how I want it to. I'm kind of new to this so be patient with me! :-)

**What I want:**

When you hover over the top level nav, I want the drop down to ease in AND I want the top level nav to slide up 20px AND I want the top level nav to have a bottom border appear. This is basically what it is doing in FF. However, when I do that, the second-tier nav is getting the same treatment. I don't want that. I want the second and third tier nav to just have a  basic hover over color. I do want all of the hover transitions to be smooth so I am using some css3 for that also.

None of this is working in IE. Also, I understand that I can use `Modernizr` to polyfil some `js` to make the `css transitions` work in older browsers, but I don't know how to do that. Can someone tell me?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/wAUx7/)   . Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Modernizr will just detect which html5/css3 features are supported by the browser so you can than target older browsers with conditional JS/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this:

```
ul#navigation li a:hover {
color:#acb453;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:10px;
border-bottom: 6px solid #4dbaf2;
```

}

to this:

```
ul#navigation .topNav > a:hover {
color:#acb453;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:10px;
border-bottom: 6px solid #4dbaf2;
```

}

And added the class "topNav" to your top level navigations. The child combinator after the topNav class limits the style to only the first anchor. Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwVwh/

Comment: do you have any idea why this isn't working at all in IE? I know IE doesn't support transitions, but i would have expected the layout to work.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/NFEt4/

Basically, you needed some way to override the styling of submenus. I did this with a new class on the nested ul.

If you haven't yet I would recommend checking out SMACSS (http://smacss.com/), I think it would help create a more flexible architecture in your CSS classes.

As for the modernizr question, maybe you could create a separate question to make sure you get a good enough answer for that?

Comment: That fiddle appears to be doing the same thing as before. Is this the right link? I've been planning on trying out SMACSS. I went to a conference last week about it. It looks so much easier!

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe! It looks like someone else solved this too.

Comment: Maybe I didn't click "Update" before I submitted the answer. I'm still getting the hang of jsfiddle. I also think @DuMaurier had a slightly cleaner solution within your architecture. Good luck!